# Custom Rails logger creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I'm using Rails 5 and need to create a custom Rails logger.

For instance in some places of the controllers I want to have this logging calls:

```
Rails.logger.info('Event happened',
  { event_id: '...', email: '...', ...}
)
```

And latter on in my log file I want to see something like this:

```
{
  "level": "info",
  "ts": 1507972311.8043,
  "caller": "controller/api/v2/news.rb:101",
  "msg": "Event happened",
  "app": "My App",
  "env": "production",
  "context": {
    "event_id": "1234567",
    "email": "example@gmail.com",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Doe"
  }
}
```

Is this possible? How to do this for all log levels (info/debug/error) at the same time?

Comment: You can use something like this.
logger.debug {"Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"}

Answer (score 1):

Create you own wrapper:

```
class LocalLogger

  def self.log(*args)
    new.log(*args)
  end

  def logger
    Rails.logger
  end
  delegate :info, :debug, :warn, :error, to: :logger

  def log(level: :info, payload)
    send(level, payload.inspect)
  end
end

LocalLogger.log level: :warn, {foo: bar}
```

Modify the `log` method to behave as you want.

However, avoid the temptation to be too clever with this - the default logger behaviour is pretty good and will behave as most other devs expect it to.

Comment: isn't working for me: ` syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER (SyntaxError)
 def log(level: :info, payload)`

Comment: Check your Ruby version. That syntax will not work with old versions of Ruby. If that's the case try `def log(level, payload)` and then use `LocalLogger.log :warn, {foo: :bar}`

Comment: `ruby -v` => `ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to declare your own [`Logger#formatter`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#class-Logger-label-Format):

```
Rails.logger.      
      instance_variable_get(:@logger).
      instance_variable_get(:@log).
      formatter = proc do |severity, datetime, progname, msg|
                    DO WHATEVER YOU WANT HERE
                  end
```

Comment: Will this not break if Rails.logger changes its implementation?

Comment: @Kris It obviously will. Relying on Rails means everything could break when Rails changes their implementation. Even `Rails.logger` might stop to exist.

Comment: It would not break, in the same major version, if you used their public API. Which is why I'd go with wrapping Rails.logger using `SimpleDelegator`.